# Removing Repetition with Java Annotations

Tags: java, annotations, dry

Is it possible to make the following code cleaner with less repetition using annotations?
I know it would be possible with java 8 closures, but trying to get this working on java 6/7

```
Variable x = new Variable(this,"HClass","HC"){
    @Override
    String getValue(Player p){
        return getHeroFromPlayer(p).getHeroClass().getName();
    }
};

Variable y = new Variable(this,"HSecClass","HSC"){
    @Override
    String getValue(Player p){
        return getHeroFromPlayer(p).getSecondClass().getName();
    }
};

Variable z = new Variable(this,"HLevel","HL"){
    @Override
    String getValue(Player p){
        return getHeroFromPlayer(p).getLevel();
    }
};

    Variable a = new Variable(this,"HMastered","HMa"){
    @Override
    String getValue(Player p){
        return getHeroFromPlayer(p).isMaster(getHeroFromPlayer(p).getHeroClass()) && (heroSClass == null || getHeroFromPlayer(p).isMaster(heroSClass))
                ? LocaleType.MESSAGE_HEROES_TRUE.getVal() : LocaleType.MESSAGE_HEROES_FALSE.getVal();;
    }
};
```

This goes on for some time, where they are all added to a map, which returns the results lazily.

---

**Edit:**     I was hoping that annotations would allow me to do something along the lines of

```
@Variable("HLevel","HL")
String getHLevel(){getHeroFromPlayer(p).getlevel();}
```

---

**Edit:** Variable.java

```
abstract class Variable {
final private VariableGroup vg;
final private List<String> keys = new Vector<String>();

Variable(VariableGroup vg,String...varargs){
    this.vg = vg;
    for (String s:varargs){
        keys.add(s);
    }
}


abstract String getValue(Player p);
```

}

Comment: To anyone having troubles with peters answer, I had to change to getDeclaredMethods() from getMethods(), But I believe this is due to changes I made, not peters example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments you can do something like this

```
@Variable("Primary Class")
public String getHClass(Player p) {
    return getHeroFromPlayer(p).getHeroClass().getName();
}

@Variable("Primary Class Level")
public int getHLevel(Player p) {
    return getHeroFromPlayer(p).getHLevel();
}

@Variable("Secondary Class")
public String getHSecClass(Player p) {
    return getHeroFromPlayer(p).getSecondClass().getName();
}

@Variable("Secondary Class Level")
public int getHLevel(Player p) {
    return getHeroFromPlayer(p).getHSecLevel();
}
```

Note: there is no need for all fields to return a String. To get this information you can do the following

```
Class heroClass = 
for(Method method : heroClass.getMethods()) {
   Variable var = method.getAnnotation(Variable.class);
   if (var == null) continue; // ignore Object.getClass()
   String description = var.value; // text to display to users
   String attributeName = method.getName().substring(3); // cut "get"
   String initials = attributeName.replaceAll("[a-z]+", "");

}
```

Comment: I was hoping that annotations would allow me to do something along the lines of 

@Variable("HLevel","HL")
String getHLevel(){getHeroFromPlayer(p).getlevel();}

Comment: @RyanTheLeach Yes you can do that. What would you do with that?  Why not use refection to call the getter?

Comment: 1. For practice at using annotations.  2. I'm still unsure on using reflection to do it, are there speed implications? and I'm not entirely sure on how to get it to "look nice"  3. the question mentions annotations, but I can edit the question if there is good reason to.

Comment: You could use annotations, but you can extract the same information from the method name.  It is more useful for additional information.  Refections is relatively expensive compared to a method call, but you are looking at a cost of around 30 nano-seconds. Is that much important to you?

Comment: "additional information" that could come in handy, I was planning on adding automatically generated documentation for all of the Variables anyway, which when reading annotation examples would make this easier.

But I'm unsure on the 30 nano-seconds part, as I'm completely oblivious to the amount of time its taking anyway, I'm assuming 30 ns wouldn't be an issue however compared to the improvement this would make.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach For documentation, you can use the Javadocs. The annotations are useful for text you can add to your running program.  BTW You can use more than one annotation.

Comment: Thanks, but if you could just provide an example, I'd love to accept your answer.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach I have added examples.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what can be improved without seeing the code for the **Variable** class.  My first question is why are you are creating anonymous inner classes just to return a value for the **getValue** method?  Why not just add a value parameter to the constructor and update the method to return that value?

Comment: That would make the value be pre-computed at the time of the Variable classes construction.

What I'm attempting to do is improve the efficiency of a method that (at the moment) is computing all of the Variables, every time it needs just one of them, when the rest are unused, by making a look-up that does the computation only when its needed.

and building the lookup only ONCE, as opposed to every time that it is used.